# Ultimate extinction probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have the PGF: 
$$
G_x(\theta) = \frac{a-1}{a-\theta^2}\;\;  a>1 = \text{constant} 
$$

I am trying to find the ultimate extinction probability $e$

and I think I need to solve 
$$e=G_x(e).$$
however I am up to the line 
$$e^3 - ae + (a-1) =0,$$
and I am unsure as to how I may proceed

Could you please help I am trying to work out if the fish in my fish tank will go extinct or not

matter of urgency

thanks

Comment: How are you unsure to proceed? you have the equation to solve.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3112703/probability-mass-function-from-a-generating-function.

Comment: Since $e=1$ is a root of this equation, divide left hand side by $e-1$ and obtain quadratic equation.